# Powershell 7: How to read from a file and add dotnet packages

Tags: .net, .net-core, powershell-core, powershell-7.0, dotnetcorecli

I am new to Powershell 7

I have a .txt log file formatted like this:

| Include | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Microsoft.ApplicationInsights | 2.17.0 |
| NewtonSoft.Json | 13.0.1 |

I need to iterate and read the package names and versions of this file and somehow insert the values into something like this:

dotnet package add {packagename}  --version {version}

Any guidance on the best approach would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A while ago, I wrote a cmdlet [**`ConvertFrom-SourceTable`**](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable) that can read a lot of (aligned) data tables including the ones from StackOverflow, see [**New Feature: Table Support**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support):

```
$Table = '
|Include                       |Version|
|------------------------------|-------|
|Microsoft.ApplicationInsights |2.17.0 |
|NewtonSoft.Json               |13.0.1 |'

$Table | ConvertFrom-SourceTable

Include                       Version
-------                       -------
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights 2.17.0
NewtonSoft.Json               13.0.1
```